# C# How do I load the references in the DLL together with the DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, sharedpreferences, .net-6.0, dllimport

I'm adding another project as a DLL reference to my Console Application project that I created with C# .NET 6.0.

In this DLL project, the reference Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is used, but this reference does not come with the added DLL.

I need to add the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient reference separately to my Console Application project. I have many references like this.

How can I ensure that the references used in the DLL are loaded together with the DLL?

Comment: Why do you have "many references like that"? Why do you use dll references?

Comment: Why are you adding it as dll reference? Add it as a project reference.

Comment: @Guru-Stron Another unit in the company is developing the project that I added as a DLL and it is not publicly available. That's why I'm adding it as a DLL. I'm looking for a way to overcome the above problems.

Comment: @tymtam Many references are used in the relevant lines of code within the related DLL project. I'm having dependency loading issues because I can't reference the project directly. How can I batch decode them within the project DLL?

Comment: If you take a dependency on a library then always make sure it came from a trustworthy source.  One that documents its requirements well and can be contacted for support when you experience a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how dependency loading would be helped by using dll references.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is to create a `nuget package` out of it, in which you include the dependencies, more on this [here (nuget)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-6.0) and here: [creating-a-package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) or like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework). If you then install the package into your new project, it will include the dependencies as well.

Alternatively you can just add the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` reference to your project.

There are all sorts of hacks to include the DLL as resource in yours, but I would stay away from that.